# Susy gem not found

Tags: rubygems, susy-compass

I'm trying to install Susy but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'susy' (>=0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I'm trying to install with the following command:

```
gem install susy
```

I'm on Windows and I've tried running the terminal as admin.

I've searched and only found a couple of really old answers that relate to old versions. I've also found an answer suggesting to use a proxy - https://askubuntu.com/questions/203632/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository but having tried a handful of them - I'm still having no luck.

This is a work machine so I'm not 100% sure on the setup but any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: can u show ur gemfile content?

Comment: Sorry, where would I find that?

Comment: tell me how U r trying to install?

Comment: `gem install susy` - I've added this to the question.

Comment: try it once ... "gem install susy --source http://rubygems.org"

Comment: That did the trick - had to add http:// to the start of the URL but installed no problem. Thanks!

Comment: yes, because "https://" was creating the issue, I am adding answer, U can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

secure server is the reason of this issue. You can Install it by using this command:

```
 gem install susy --source http://rubygems.org
```

by default its using https://rubygem.org as the source for the gem.

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1
errno=0 state=SSSLv3 read server certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer working behind a proxy?